# Backbone.js: Model, Collection, Router, when and why?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm still trying to get my head around Backbone.js
I've watched some screencasts and read some tutorials. I also RTFM. But, I'm a little confused on how everyone seems to use parts of the framework to handle different tasks.

I decided to make my first shot at backbone.js in a real app, after playing with the traditional todo list app.

My app will receive a JSON object full of questions. Then, I like to have an 'ul' where I can move around those questions (next q, previous q). I already have a view that shows the buttons and notifies whenever a user clicks 'next' or 'prev'. My question is: where should I handle the logic for my 'currentQuestion', 'next', and 'previous' functionality. I've seen some folks using a Collection for this, and some other using a Model. It confuses me.

Anyone can point me some meta-code to handle this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't really a right answer to this question. There is certainly more than one way to make it work and that is one of the nice things about Backbonejs: it is very flexible and it doesn't impose too many design choices on you.

If I were to start building what you are describing, I would certainly have:

- a `Question` model
- a `Questions` collection
- a `QuestionView` for rendering out a single question
- a `QuestionsIndexView` for displaying a list of questions

After that is where things get a little fuzzy, and it depends on what your requirements are for the app. If you wanted the state to be stored like a traditional website you might use a router and do something that looks something like this:

```
 ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
       "": "index",
       "question/:id": "show"
    },

    index: function() {
        // render a QuestionsIndexView...
    },

    show: function(id) {
        // find the q and render a QuestionView...
    }
 })
```

This is nice because state is maintained in the URLs so the user can use the browsers fwd and back buttons and things would probably work as they would expect. The problem with this is, how are we supposed to make those `nextQuestion` and `previousQuestion` buttons work?

If you make them part of the `QuestionView` a question would have to know what its next and previous questions' ids were. You could probably come up with a scheme to make this work, but a more elegant and frequently used pattern is to create another model that exists above all of the data models we have mentioned already called `App` and then make the `QuestionsCollection` and `current_question_id` attributes of this model. We would then update this `current_question_id` attr in the routers methods.

Now we are really cooking, our application state is not only persisted in the URLs of the browser, but it also exists at the application layer as an observable object. We can easily create a `ButtonsPanelView` that gets passed this `App` model and triggers the correct routes when its buttons are clicked. It is also trivial to implement `hasNextQuestion` and `hasPreviousQuestion` in the `App` model and use it to `toggle` or disable the respective buttons when the user cant go back or forward.

EDIT as requested:

To make an `App` model that exists above everything else is quite simple. You probably already have code somewhere that looks like this:

```
window._qs = new Questions();
window._qs.fetch();
```

Just do this instead:

```
var qs = new Questions();
window.app = new App({questions: qs});
qs.fetch();
```

now are `Questions` collection is an attribute of the app model, just as we wanted. So what is the definition for `App` going to look like? Again, there are many ways to go about this, but I like to use [Backbone.Models's validate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate) to make sure I don't slip into a bad state. Here's what I might do:

```
App = Backbone.Model.extend({

   defaults: {
      current_question_index: 0
   },

   validate: function(attrs) {

      if(typeof attrs.current_question_index !== "undefined") {
         // we are trying the change the question index,
         // so make sure it is valid
         var len = this.get("questions").length
         if(attrs.current_question_index < 0 || attrs.current_question_index >= len) {
            // returning anything prevents invalid set
            return "index is out of bounds"; 
         }
      }
    },

    hasNextQ: function() {
      var next_ind = this.get("current_question_index") + 1;
      // use the logic we already created, in validate() but
      // convert it to a bool. NOTE in javascript:
      //       !"stuff"   === false
      //       !undefined === true 
      return !this.validate({current_question_index: next_ind}); 
    },

    nextQ: function() {
      var next_ind = this.get("current_question_index") + 1;
      // validate() will prevent us from setting an invalid index
      return this.set("current_question_index", next_ind);

    }

});
```

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, I've seen collection-level views referred to as index views.  Thus, `QuestionsView` could be `QuestionIndexView`, which is more visually distinctive from `QuestionView`.  I otherwise agree with your points and would add that Backbone's multiple-ways-of-doing-something can sometimes feel overwhelming

Comment: I updated it to read `QuestionsIndexView`. In terms of overwhelmingness, I agree that it makes it a little trickier when first learning but I think it comes with the payoff of being more versatile when you want to do something out of the ordinary. There are also other frameworks that impose a stricter architecture and thus a little more consistency. IMHO [Emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) is an example

Comment: @Mathew, your answer is great. It really shred some light on this! I hope this is not asking to much, but can you elaborate on how to make a "model that exists above all data". That's exactly where I am stuck. I have n number of questions, I know I'd start at 0, but I wanna move that index to +1 and -1 whenever the user click 'next' or previous and update my views accordingly. That's why I used backbone.js after all! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fedeisas sure, see my most recent edit, I only did it in one direction (next), but previous is the same idea

Answer (score 1):

As what I understood in BackboneJS, a "model" is a unit of data. For example, a unit data for a "to-do item" would contain:

- a date
- a message
- a status

These units of data are stored in a "collection". They are synonymous to "database tables" which contain "rows". But model data is not restricted to 2-d like a row. Then Backbone "views" do the logic as well a interact with the interface - more like a "View-Controller". The view houses the event handlers, the code that adds and removes elements, changes interface etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. It seems I'm more used to the server-side definition of model (a model can return several rows) so that really confused me. Thanks!